# Delete border of matrix

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a 2d array[,] and I need to delete the **border** of it (or create a new array without it). I tried everything I thought of and nothing worked since I don't usually work with 2d arrays. Help please?

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
```

becomes:

```
6 7
1 2
```

```
Queue<int> numbers = new Queue<int>();

int[,] b = new int[4, 4];
for (int i = 0; i < b.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < b.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        b[i, j] = x;
    }
}
int rows = b.GetLength(0);
Console.WriteLine("Number of rows: "+rows);
int columns = b.GetLength(1);
Console.WriteLine("Number of columns: " + columns);


int[,] arrayUpdated = new int[columns - 2,rows - 2];
for (int n = 0; n < b.GetUpperBound(1); n++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < b.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        arrayUpdated[i, n] = b[i, n];
        Console.WriteLine(arrayUpdated[i, n]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lynn, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide some details on what you've tried and why they failed?

Comment: Please post at least some of the code you've tried.

Comment: I tried creating an updated array without the border by copying the original array (without the first and last columns and rows) into the updated array, BUT it gives me the error: invalidoperationexception

Comment: You should iterate from 1 to the bound minus 1 and then just do `arrayUpdate[i-1, n-1] = b[i,n]`

Comment: " iterate from 1 to the bound minus 1 " sorry, I'm not a native English speaker, could you explain please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static T[,] RemoveBorders<T>(T[,] source)
{
    //index of last item, not number of items
    var ROW = source.GetUpperBound(0);
    if (ROW < 2) throw new ArgumentException("source array is not tall enough");

    var COL = source.GetUpperBound(1);          
    if (COL < 2) throw new ArgumentException("source array is not wide enough");

    var result = new T[ROW - 1, COL - 1];       
    for (int r = 1; r < ROW; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 1; c < COL; c++)
        {
            result[r-1, c-1] = source[r, c];    
        }
    }   
    return result;
}
```

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/dtUpRA

You would use it in the code in the question like this:

```
int[,] arrayUpdated = RemoveBorders(b);
```

Comment: @LynnDanilov: It's your original array.  Source is a 2-dimensional array of T (where T is any type - in your case, it's an `int`.  If you pass your array in, you will get a new array coming out.  Notice the calls to `GetUpperBounds`, that gets the bounds (the width or height) of the array

Comment: Also note that array indexing starts at zero and goes to `Length-1` (in both dimensions)

Comment: Thank you very much!!